# issues running SD (no module named 'ldm.models'; ldm is not a package)

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning

I am trying to run my code on a remote server because I needed more GPU but now I am getting this error and I don't understand how to fix it or what it means.
Has anyone had this issue or know how to fix it? I would really appreciate your help, spent hours already trying to resolve :(

```
[2022-12-07 05:27:14] main.py -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  eprint(line:60) :: Error when calling Cognitive Face API:
status_code: 401
code: 401
message: Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource.
[2022-12-07 05:27:14] main.py -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  eprint(line:60) :: img_url:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Windows/master/Data/detection1.jpg
[2022-12-07 05:27:15] main.py -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  eprint(line:60) :: Error when calling Cognitive Face API:
status_code: 401
code: 401
message: Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource.
[2022-12-07 05:27:15] main.py -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  eprint(line:60) :: img_url:/data1/mingmingzhao/label/data_sets_teacher_1w/47017613_1510574400_out-video-jzc70f41fa6f7145b4b66738f81f082b65_f_1510574403268_t_1510575931221.flv_0001.jpg
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
from ldm.models.diffusion.ddim import DDIMSampler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldm.models'; 'ldm' is not a package
```

when I ran this on local computer, had no issue besides it being super slow. not sure what I am missing!

I tried searching online and checking to make sure the ldm package was there, I checked versions of ldm and python.